# How to handle empty array in static list without throwing error in ngx typeahead?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, typeahead

I have attached the ngx official plunker link.
Here i'm using static list for displaying typeahead

http://embed.plnkr.co/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3/

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'static-list',
      template: `
      <h3>Using STATIC list</h3>
      <section class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="search-results style-3">
          <input type="text" ngxTypeahead [value]="query3" [taList]="staticList" (taSelected)="handleStaticResultSelected($event)">
        </div>
      </section>
      `
    })
    export class StaticListComponent {
      public query3 = '';
      public staticList = [
        'guitar',
        'drums',
        'bass',
        'keyboards',
        'mic',
        'trumpet',
        'horns',
        'pedals'
      ];

      public handleStaticResultSelected (result) {
        this.query = result;
      }

    }
```

I'm matching with some condition locally and sometimes the `staticList` might be empty for me. How to handle this empty array error here?

Is there any way to do something like this in template? or any other possible solutions?

```
[taList]="filteredList!==undefined | slice:0:5"
```

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue?

Comment: @yurzui you can make the staticList empty and check

Comment: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` ?

Comment: Have you tried `[taList]="staticList || something"`?

Comment: @yurzui No.I'm getting this ..Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
errors.js:55 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "JSONP Error", url: "?q=j&callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0", ok: false, …}

Comment: I added slice to filter only 5..but even without that i'm getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164997/discussion-between-ramya-s-and-yurzui).

Comment: If you have empty array then it will remain empty. Check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3?p=preview

Comment: In console, you can see the error.. My problem is if i add any value to that empty staticList typeahead is not working..

Comment: Seems I didn't save plunker. Here is new version https://plnkr.co/edit/yPRlSP86qeXb8j4vafpd?p=preview

Comment: I need to fill in the array and if user types something i'll make it empty and fill in some new values according to input..So i can't initialize and keep like that..

Answer (score 0):

If your list is empty then `[taList]="listname"` won't show any error and hence no suggestion in input field.